# How to iterate over the first index of 4D matrix every nth element?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, indexing

Assume there is a 4D matrix `a=(20,3,100,100)`. I want to divide the first index of `a` which is `20` into `4` batches within a for loop and then append each iteration into output. I don't want to use reshape since each batch will be fed into a network.

The size of the output should be `(4,5,3,100,100)`

Here is my try:

```
output=[]
a=np.random.randint(0,100,size=(20,3,600,600))
for i in a[1:20:5,:,:,:] :  
            cnn_in=a[i,:,:,:]
            output.append(cnn_in)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this?

```
for i in range(0,20,5):
     cnn_in=a[i:i+5]
     output.append(cnn_in)
```

or simpler with `np.split`: `output=np.split(a,4)`